# Value on Spinner can't post to databae mySql

Tags: java, android, spinner

logcat doesn't give me a specific error, it only shows the error location, which is on line 155 `{id_status = spStatus.getSelectedItem().toString();}`

I don't know the right keyword to solve the error. I've been browsing, and I think this is the same as the tutorial I followed. where is my mistake? give me more detailed instructions

**my java like this:**

```
package src.bkkpost.loker;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import src.bkkpost.MainActivity;
import src.bkkpost.R;
import src.bkkpost.loker.adapter.AdapterStatus;
import src.bkkpost.model.Value;
import src.bkkpost.util.BaseApiService;
import src.bkkpost.util.SharedPrefManager;
import src.bkkpost.util.UtilsApi;

public class UpdateLoker extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    //string spinner kelamin
    String[] idStatus = {"10", "20"};
    String[] nama_status = {"Buka", "Tutup"};

    //string spinner kelamin
    String[] id_kelamin = {"5001", "5002", "5003"};
    String[] nama_kelamin = {"Pria/Wanita", "Pria", "Wanita"};

    //string spinner pendidikan
    String[] pendidikan_id = {"3001", "3002", "3003", "30004", "3005", "3006", "3007"};
    String[] nama_pendidikan = {"SD", "SMP", "SMA", "SMK ", "Diploma/(D3)", "Sarjana/(S1)", "Master/(S2)"};

    //string spinner pendidikan
    String[] jurusan_id = {"30001", "300301", "300302", "3000401", "3000402", "3000403", "3000404",
            "3000405", "3000406", "3000407", "3000408", "3000409", "3000410", "3000411", "3000412", "3000413", "3000414",
            "3000415", "300501", "300502", "300503", "300504", "300505", "300506", "300075"};
    String[] nama_jurusan = {"Semua Jurusan", "IPA", "IPS", "Administrasi Perkantoran ", "Akuntansi ", "ANalisis Kimia ",
            "Animasi ", "Broadcasting ", "Elektronik ", "Farmasi ", "Multimedia ", "Otomotif ", "Pariwisata ", "Pemasaran ",
            "Perbankan ", "Perhotelan", "Tata Boga ", "Tata Busana ", "Perpajakan(D3/S1) ", "Broadcasting(D3/S1)", "Teknik Mesin(D3/S1)",
            "Pariwisata(D3/S1)", "Sekretaris (D3/S1)", "Hubungan Masyarakat (D3/S1)", "Akuntansi(D3/S1) "};

    AutoCompleteTextView date;
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    BaseApiService mApiservice;
    ProgressDialog loading;
    Context mContex;
    SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;
    public static final String URL = "http://192.168.43.164/gokerja/";
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    String bkk_id, posisi, nama_pt, alamat_pt, waktu_buka, id_status;
    @BindView(R.id.post_btn_upload)
    Button btnUpload;



    @BindView(R.id.post_bkk_id)
    TextView tvBkkid;
    @BindView(R.id.post_posisi)
    AutoCompleteTextView etPosisi;
    @BindView(R.id.post_namaperusahaan)
    AutoCompleteTextView etNamaperusahan;
    @BindView(R.id.post_alamat_pt)
    AutoCompleteTextView etAlamat;
    @BindView(R.id.post_tanggal)
    AutoCompleteTextView etTangggal;
    @BindView(R.id.post_spin_statusup)
    Spinner spStatus;

    @OnClick(R.id.post_btn_upload)
    void daftar() { }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loker_update_loker);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(this);
        tvBkkid.setText(sharedPrefManager.getSPNama());

        mApiservice = UtilsApi.getAPIService();
        mContex = this;

        date = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.post_tanggal);
        date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = c.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
                int mMont = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int mDay = c.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                //date picker dialog
                datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(UpdateLoker.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                                date.setText(year + "-"
                                        + (month + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);
                            }
                        }, mYear, mMont, mDay);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        //get spinner status
        final Spinner spinnerStatus = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.post_spin_statusup);
        spinnerStatus.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        AdapterStatus adapterStatus = new AdapterStatus(getApplicationContext(), idStatus);
        spinnerStatus.setAdapter(adapterStatus);

        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (etPosisi.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    etPosisi.setError("Posisi harus di isi");
                } else if (etNamaperusahan.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    etNamaperusahan.setError("Perusahaan harus di isi");
                } else if (etAlamat.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    etAlamat.setError("alamat harus di isi");
                } else {
                    //Untuk menampilkan progress dialog

                    progress.setCancelable(false);
                    progress.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progress.show();

                    bkk_id = tvBkkid.getText().toString();
                    posisi = etPosisi.getText().toString();
                    nama_pt = etNamaperusahan.getText().toString();
                    alamat_pt = etAlamat.getText().toString();
                    waktu_buka = etTangggal.getText().toString();
                    id_status = spStatus.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(URL)
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();

                    BaseApiService api = retrofit.create(BaseApiService.class);
                    Call<Value> call = api.post_loker(bkk_id, posisi, nama_pt, alamat_pt, waktu_buka, id_status);

                    call.enqueue(new Callback<Value>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<Value> call, Response<Value> response) {
                            String value = response.body().getValue();
                            String message = response.body().getMessage();
                            progress.dismiss();

                            if (value.equals("1")) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(UpdateLoker.this);
                                alert.setTitle("Confirm");
                                alert.setMessage("Iklan Lowongan kerja telah berhasil dibuat");
                                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        startActivity(new Intent(mContex, MainActivity.class));

                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                                alert.show();
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(UpdateLoker.this);
                                alert.setTitle("Confirm");
                                alert.setMessage("Terjadi Kesalahan Jaringan, Iklan gagal dibuat");
                                alert.setPositiveButton("Coba Lagi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        startActivity(new Intent(mContex, UpdateLoker.class));

                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                                alert.show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<Value> call, Throwable t) {
                            t.printStackTrace();
                            progress.dismiss();
                            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(UpdateLoker.this);
                            alert.setTitle("Error 301");
                            alert.setMessage("Terjadi kesalahan jaringan, Iklan gagal dibuat");
                            alert.setPositiveButton("Coba Lagi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            alert.show();
                            //Toast.makeText(UpdateLoker.this, "semelekete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

**this my Logcat**

```
09-04 17:13:15.904 16015-16015/src.bkkpost D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-04 17:13:15.904 16015-16015/src.bkkpost W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419f3d58)

                                                       --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
09-04 17:13:15.904 16015-16015/src.bkkpost E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: src.bkkpost, PID: 16015
                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                 at src.bkkpost.loker.UpdateLoker$2.onClick(UpdateLoker.java:155)
                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: _logchat doesn't give me a specific error_ Actually it does, it's a `NullPointerException`, either your `spStatus` is null or `spStatus.getSelectedItem()` is returning (or accessing) to a null property. Debugger is your friend here.